# Accordion dropdown with travel logic component

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, accordion, dropdown

I want to create a dropdown accordion with specific behaviors :

- Each time a accordion is shown, **an AJAX request is performed** to get all items information;
- When deploying the dropdown, the first accordion must be shown;
- **Each time the user click on an accordion item, clicked item must be close, and the next one should be open;**
- By clicking on an item in the final accordion, the dropdown should be closed.

I've created the dropdown first of all. Please click on the Tachometer:

**https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LzmjJe**

Here is the javascript :

```
$(window).ready(function () {

    // Collapse accordion every time dropdown is shown
    $('.dropdown-accordion').on('show.bs.dropdown', function (event) {
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideDown();
        var accordion = $(this).find($(this).data('accordion'));
        accordion.find('.panel-collapse.in').collapse('hide')
    });

    // Collapse accordion every time dropdown is shown
    $('.dropdown-accordion').on('shown.bs.dropdown', function (event) {
        //Afficher le collapse commune
        $("#collapseCommune").collapse('show');
    });

    $('.dropdown-accordion').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function () {
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideUp();
    });

    // Prevent dropdown to be closed when we click on an accordion link
    $('.dropdown-accordion').on('click', 'a[data-toggle="collapse"]', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        $($(this).data('parent')).find('.panel-collapse.in').collapse('hide')
        $($(this).attr('href')).collapse('show');
    })

    $(".dropdown-accordion #collapseCommune").on("show.bs.collapse", function () { // Occurs when the collapse commune is shown
        var element = $(this)
        $(".dropdown-accordion #collapseCommune > .panel-body").empty();
        $.ajax({
            url: "somewhere",
            method: 'GET',
            datatype: "json",
            timeout: 5000,
            beforeSend: function () {
                //LOADING
                element.append("<div class='loader'></div>")
            },
            success: function (res) {
                //ENQUEUE CHART
                console.log(res);
                element.find(".loader").remove();
                res.forEach(function (element) {
                    addItemToAccordion($(".dropdown-accordion #collapseCommune > .panel-body"), element, "accordion-commune");
                })
            },
            error: function (err) {
                //SHOW ERROR
                //element.find(".loader").remove();
            }
        });
    })
})
```

But i'm stuck for the rest, mainly because creating a component might be better, but i don't know how to begin.

Please suggest a module which work similar to mentioned above.

Comment: you mean document ready...

Comment: what do you mean ?